# React - Pass parameter to app with data on root element

Tags: html, reactjs, react-dom

I have a bit of an odd use case for a react app, I'd like to provide a root URL to the app based on a parameter on the element we mount the react app on.

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyGoodApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Where in the HTML DOM I have

```
<div id="root" data-param="https://website.biz/api/"></div>
```

I can't find anything particularly in the documentation that covers this case. I'm constrained in deploying this app due to business constraints so need to pass the value in this way or a similar way if possible. The value will be dynamic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just do what you would normally fetch an attribute from DOM, get its attribute and send it as a prop to the React component

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.message}</div>
  }
}

const el = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(<App message={el.getAttribute('data-param')} />, el)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" data-param="https://website.biz/api/"></div>
```

Comment: And bippity-boppity-boo? What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself
! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob I usually post code and then add comments, sorry for the confusion...

Comment: This is the way to do it, just pass a prop like you would do with any other component. To get the value of the data attribute you could also use `dataset` instead of `getAttribute`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes